# In app billing android gives error -1005?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am going to implement managed in app billing in android I have tried a trivial sample application but when I run the app on a  device it gives me error.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong and why this error occurred.

First display popup 
[image]

when I click OK than it give me error on log.

Second display popup
[image]

```
06-23 14:37:04.912: E/Trivial Drive(19340): **** Trivial Drive Error: Error purchasing: IabResult: User canceled. (response: -1005:User cancelled)
```

Comment: i use the sample app from sdk and i replace the   String base64EncodedPublicKey   and after that i have implement this in my app same class

Comment: i think other thing is done by sample

Comment: The item was not found because you haven't added item to the app in the google play console.

Comment: check this link i have added this item in playstore http://screencast.com/t/2IzofifRr53b

Comment: @berserk have you check the screen shot are you talking about this

Comment: i am googling but still not got for this solution

Comment: hey one more question i have added only base64 public key anything is need to add in code

Comment: @Mahesh base64 key and the key of the item name you are using on playstore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56104/discussion-between-mahesh-and-berserk).

Comment: key of item name means product id which we created for in app product if i am right than where to set this key ?

Answer (score 3):

It is simple: *Google Play In-app purchase testing is not so intuitive.*

To test new IAPs you should **upload a Beta version of your App** (with all logic already implemented) and register some test accounts to download that Beta Version and test.

Every change you should upload a new Beta Version and the error wont appear anymore.

**PS:**
To ensure the logic is working fine, you should use test billing IDs listed here: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html